# How to show that two quadratic forms are equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

To show to quadratic forms are not equivalent, we can find rank, or discriminant or some element which is represented by either one only etc. But Is there a general criterion to show that two binary(right now I am only concerned for binary) quadratic forms are equivalent.
Like here is an example which uses variable transformation, but every time find what transformation will apply is tough.

$\textbf{Example-}$ $X^2-Y^2 $ and $4XY$. replacing $X,Y$ by $X+Y,X-Y$ do the job here. Nnow there are criterion which gives an equivalent condition to check whether two binary forms are equivalent or not , like

$\textbf{Criterion 1-}$ On algebraically closed fields, same dimension and same rank suffice.

$\textbf{Criterion 2-}$ On Reals, same rank and same signature suffices.

$\textbf{Criterion 3-}$ On finite fields,same discriminant is enough.

But in general if we are given field as some arbitrary $K$, then what to do? I am very new at quadratic forms. Any help will be appreciated.

I know that we can check similarity of their corresponding matrices, but is there any other way, beside checking matrices are similar or not. Like how would you proceed on these couple of question below. If there is no other method, can somebody please explain me the method to check whether two matrices are similar or not, I am really weak with matrices.

$\textbf{Question 1-}$ Prove $X^2-4XY+3Y^2, X^2-Y^2,aX^2-aY^2$ are equivalent over $K$.

$\textbf{Question 2-}$ Show

i) $X^2-Y^2 \sim XY$ over $K$,   ii) $3X^2-2Y^2 \sim X^2-6Y^2$ (over $Q$)

Comment: Can you give me the reference for your three criterions?

Comment: I don't remember where I studied these criterion from but most probably Algebra Vol. 3, Modules, Luthar and Passi.

Answer (score 0):

Q1)

a) $X^2-Y^2$ is already in diagonal from. It's matrix is  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.
b) $aX^2-aY^2$ is already in diagonal from. It's matrix is  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a& 0 \\ 0 & -a \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$. We have  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a& 0 \\ 0 & -a \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \sim \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
c) $X^2-4XY+3Y^2$ can also be written as $(X-2Y)^2-Y^2$
Result a) and b): if $K=\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ they are always equivalent. If $\sqrt(a)$ is rational and $K=\Bbb{Q}$ then also, and when $K$ is a finite field then if the characteristic is $2$ then always otherwise only when $a=\pm 1$.
Result (b) and (c) always equivalent (same discriminant, rank and signature).

Q2)

i) if in the second we replace $X=U+V$ and $Y=U-V$ then we get $XY=(U+V)(U-V)=U^2-V^2$, so equivalence.
ii) $3X^2-2Y^2 \sim 3(3X^2-2Y^2)=(3X)^2-6Y^2=U^2-6V^2$

Comment: My question was can you tell me the techniques, or method behind approaching these problems? thanks

Comment: I always used the notion of quadratic forms on real vector spaces. As I went through the literature I met several conflicting definitions of the notion equivalent. What is the definition you useN

Comment: That their corresponding matrices are congruent.

Comment: Congruent in this sense?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence and not in the sense of similar $A=T^{-1}BT$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence sense

Comment: Ok, well for symmetric matrices this is the same. But there is another problem, if the vector space is over $\Bbb{Q}$, and the form diagonalizes but with irrational eigenvalues are the forms then still equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but the answer to Question 2(b) in the accepted answer is incorrect and should be corrected.

The forms $f(x,y)=x^2-6y^2$ and $g(x,y)= 2x^2-3y^2$ are not equivalent over $Q$. This can be seen as $g(x,y)$ does not represent the value $1$ over the rationals.  If $g(x,y)$ did represent 1, then the form

$h(x,y,z)= 2x^2-3y^2-z^2$

would have an non-zero integer solution.  However, this does not happen, for when $(x,y,z)=1$, the equation does not have a solution $\mod 8$.